Will a `Box` that loses its ownership `drop` like be std::mem::replace?
I'm follow the book Learn Rust With Entirely Too Many Linked Lists
The related source code is provided below. Please pay attention to the impl Drop for List section:

#![allow(unused)]
fn main() {
use std::mem;

pub struct List {
    head: Link,
}

enum Link {
    Empty,
    More(Box<Node>),
}

struct Node {
    elem: i32,
    next: Link,
}

impl List {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        List { head: Link::Empty }
    }

    pub fn push(&mut self, elem: i32) {
        let new_node = Box::new(Node {
            elem: elem,
            next: mem::replace(&mut self.head, Link::Empty),
        });

        self.head = Link::More(new_node);
    }

    pub fn pop(&mut self) -> Option<i32> {
        match mem::replace(&mut self.head, Link::Empty) {
            Link::Empty => None,
            Link::More(node) => {
                self.head = node.next;
                Some(node.elem)
            }
        }
    }
}

impl Drop for List {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        let mut cur_link = mem::replace(&mut self.head, Link::Empty);

        while let Link::More(mut boxed_node) = cur_link {
            cur_link = mem::replace(&mut boxed_node.next, Link::Empty);
        }
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod test {
    use super::List;

    #[test]
    fn basics() {
        let mut list = List::new();

        // Check empty list behaves right
        assert_eq!(list.pop(), None);

        // Populate list
        list.push(1);
        list.push(2);
        list.push(3);

        // Check normal removal
        assert_eq!(list.pop(), Some(3));
        assert_eq!(list.pop(), Some(2));

        // Push some more just to make sure nothing's corrupted
        list.push(4);
        list.push(5);

        // Check normal removal
        assert_eq!(list.pop(), Some(5));
        assert_eq!(list.pop(), Some(4));

        // Check exhaustion
        assert_eq!(list.pop(), Some(1));
        assert_eq!(list.pop(), None);
    }
}
}

My question is: Can I replace the drop function with something like
impl Drop for List {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        let mut cur_link = mem::replace(&mut self.head, Link::Empty);

        while let Link::More(boxed_node) = cur_link {
            cur_link = boxed_node.next;
        }
    }
}

My idea is that cur_link = boxed_node.next will consume ownership of boxed_node.next, allowing boxed_node to be dropped without recursion. I have compiled my code, and it works. Is this the correct approach, or have I missed something?
I understand that cur_link = mem::replace(&mut boxed_node.next, Link::Empty) sets the next field of boxed_node to empty, thus preventing recursive drop. In this case, would it be feasible to directly consume ownership of boxed_node.next instead?

Yes, this will work fine. Semantically, this is actually cleaner as the drop glue for the next field won't even need to be emitted (though the replace-based approach will probably have the drop glue optimized away anyway, just at a later compilation phase).
You might be wondering why this works, though.  Won't Box's Drop implementation get called?  How would this implementation know that the next field doesn't need to be dropped?
The answer is that Box is special, and has special-case code in the compiler.  From a Box<T>, you can move the T out just by dereferencing the box.  In your code, you found that you can also partially move the T held in a Box<T>.  This is because, when dropping a Box<T>, the compiler emits code to drop the contained T.  Box<T>'s Drop implementation does not drop the contained T.
In your case, this allows you to partially move from the Node in a Box<Node>.  The compiler tracks this like any other non-Box partial move, and simply omits the drop glue code for moved fields.
